# Backbone. Different model change

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Changing the model in backbone. I am using normally model.set or model.unset to change some model values. And it shows normally on the UI (binded).

I have done something differently now, change the model by reference. It works OK as far as I can see, but I am wondering is it OK regarding Backbone.

I am doing sorting on the model (based on UI change, that UI is not binded), and I am doing it by reference. So I am not using set provided by backbone.

This is what I do:

```
var source = this.model.get('mymodel'),
            temp = source[startMove];               
            temp.age= endMove; 

            if (startMove <= endMove) {
                for (var i = 1; i < endMove; i++) {
                    if (i >= startMove) {
                        source[i] = source[i + 1];
                        source[i].age--;
                    }
                }

                 // Rest of the code
```

In short I manipulate not the model by using set command, but rather source value.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I cannot seem to find anything wrong with this. What's the issue?

Comment: It works as expected. Just wondering if there might be potential issues that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont get your `change:*` events triggered and your model wont validate against its validation method. Consider this example:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model();
var o = {};
model.set('o', o);
o.hello = 1;

model.get('o').hello; // 1;
```

---

```
On the other hand when getting from a backbone model you will get the value stored in `model.attributes[attr]`. So actually you can also set like in your example:

var local_o = model.get('o');

local_o.hello = 2;

model.get('o').hello; // 2;
```

If would always use `.set` so my model can validate and all my change events gets triggered; Also you can use `_.clone` to make a shallow close of the object:

```
var local_o = _.clone(model.get('o'));

local_o.hello = 3;

model.get('o').hello; // 2
```

Comment: Just wondering, I am having a lots of sorting. I will probably end up with lots of models, with lots of properties. I do not have concern with events and validation at this stage. Since I do not have any. Is there a speed benefit?